# Android Studio keeps asking to turn off Hyper-V in an infinite loop

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v

I am running Windows 10 and just now installed Android Studio. Android Studio keeps asking to turn off Hyper-V in an infinite loop, for a very basic empty application. I don't even have Hyper-V installed.

How do I proceed?
Screenshot of Windows programs installed & Android Studio error

[image: [1]]

Comment: do you use visual studio ?

Comment: Yes. Why do you ask? I prefer using Android Studio for Android development though.

Comment: the Hyper-V hypervisor, is used by Visual Studio as well as the emulator thats why i asked to v.studio guys get this thing normally with android stido  **go to Run – Edit Configurations and see whats there under Deployment Target Options**

Comment: If you have v.studio up and running turn off it and try to run emulator in android studio and see if it works

Comment: I use VS but on other systems. I don't have Visual Studio on this laptop.

Comment: How do I proceed??

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue too and it was because of VBS (virtualization based security) features in Windows. If Device Guard or Credential Guard are enabled on your machine, that machine is using Hyper-V's hypervisor. You can check it using System Information (msinfo32.exe).

[image]

Generally this is enabled via Group Policy. You will need to work with organization to opt out of those policies.

Comment: What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running **Android Studio** on a Windows **VMWare** machine, Android Studio keeps asking to turn off Hyper-V as you said.to solve this you should enable "*virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-RVI*" on your Windows VMWare machine.
turn of Windows VMWare machine.

1. select your *Windows VMWare* Machine.
2. press "*Edit Virtual machine setting*".
3. select "*processors*".
4. enable "*virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-RVI*".
   press ok and power on your Windows VMWare machine.

[image: steps:]